# if / and statement for URL with strpos

Tags: php, strpos

I have the following three possible urls..

- www.mydomain.com/445/loggedin/?status=empty
- www.mydomain.com/445/loggedin/?status=complete
- www.mydomain.com/445/loggedin/

The www.mydomain.com/445 part is dynamically generated and is different each time so I can't do an exact match, how can i detect the following...

- If $url contains loggedin but DOES NOT CONTAIN either /?status=empty OR /?status=complete

Everything I try fails as no matter what it will always detect the logged in part..

```
if(strpos($referrer, '?status=empty')) {
echo 'The status is empty';
}
elseif(strpos($referrer, '?status=complete')) {
echo 'The status is complete';
}
elseif(strpos($referrer, '/loggedin/')) {
echo 'The status is loggedin';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Slice up the URL into segments

```
$path = explode('/',$referrer);
$path = array_slice($path,1);
```

Then just use your logic on that array, the first URL you included would return this:

```
Array ( [0] => 445 [1] => loggedin [2] => ?status=empty )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$referrer = 'www.mydomain.com/445/loggedin/?status=empty';

// turn the referrer into an array, delimited by the /
$url = explode('/', $referrer);

// the statuses we check against as an array
$statuses = array('?status=complete', '?status=empty');

// If "loggedin" is found in the url, and count the array_intersect matches, if the matches = 0, none of the statuses you specified where found
if( in_array('loggedin', $url) && count(array_intersect($url, $statuses)) == 0 )
{
    echo 'The user is logged in';
}
// if the complete status exists in the url
else if( in_array('?status=complete', $url) )
{
    echo 'The status is complete';
}
// if the empty status exists in the url
else if( in_array('?status=empty', $url) )
{
    echo 'The status is empty';
}
```

I would recommend looking at [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), it is quite useful.

Hope it helps, not sure if this is the best way of doing it, but might spark your imagination.

Answer (score 0):

Strpos is probably not what you want to use for this.  You could do it with stristr:

```
    if($test_str = stristr($referrer, '/loggedin/')) 
    {
        if(stristr($test_str, '?status=empty')) 
        {
            echo 'empty';
        }
        elseif (stristr($test_str, '?status=complete')) 
        {
            echo 'complete';
        } else {
            echo 'logged in';
        }
    }
```

But it's probably easier/better to do it with regular expressions:

```
if(preg_match('/\/loggedin\/(\?status=(.+))?$/', $referrer, $match)) 
{
    if(count($match)==2) echo "The status is ".$match[2];
    else echo "The status is logged in";
}
```